# System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'System.String'.'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, objectdisposedexception

I have this code that should upload all `Attachment` sent by user:

```cs
private async Task<List<AttchmentsMetaData>> UploadAttachments(IEnumerable<IFormFile> Attachments, string TaskTitle)
{
    // 1. Configure storage location and path generation
     string uploadPath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "attachments",$"{TaskTitle}" ); 
    
    List<AttchmentsMetaData> metaData = [];
    // 2. Process and store each uploaded file
    Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadPath);
    foreach (IFormFile attach in Attachments)
    {
        string uniqueFileName = attach.FileName;
        string fullPath = Path.Combine(uploadPath, uniqueFileName);

        using (FileStream stream =  new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await attach.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }
        metaData.Add( new AttchmentsMetaData {id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), OriginalFileName = attach.FileName, ContentType = attach.ContentType, FileSize = attach.Length });
    }
    return (metaData);
}
```

If `Attachment` has only one item it works, but if has more than one it fails in the second iteration  giving the above error:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'System.String'.'

I tried to add manual dispose for the file stream.
I tried to call the function multiple times and passing just one item.

Edited :

This is more info
The thread 0x3838 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
An exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code
Cannot access a disposed object.

Object name: 'System.String'.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FileBufferingReadStream.set_Position(Int64 value)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.FormFile.OpenReadStream()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.FormFile.CopyToAsync(Stream target, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at ticketing_system_Dev_Nxt_level.Services.TaskService.UploadAttachments(IEnumerable`1 Attachments, String TaskTitle) in D:\ASP.NET\ticketing-system-Dev-Nxt-level\Services\TaskService.cs:line 334

Comment: Please include the stack trace. The object throwing `ObjectDisposedException` should be reporting its own type, not `System.String`. Strings are not disposable so the thrower of the exception is lying.

Comment: I think the issue is that you are disposing the streams too early. I think they need to still be open when you send the message. Don't use a `using` block in this case. Dispose the attachments and streams manually after sending the message.

Comment: So if the user uploads a file called `..\..\something` they could overwrite something important? Beware of path traversal attacks.

Comment: I did a little digging and found that an internal type used to read the attachment, `ReferenceReadStream` is using `ObjectDisposedException.ThrowIf(bool,object)` incorrectly. It's passing a string as the *object instance* parameter, and then the exception is reporting the "System.String" in the exception instead of the type of the object throwing it. So it's something to do with how `attach` is being used that's getting to that call site. ***Again***, provide the stack trace from the exception so we can figure out exactly why it's happening.

Comment: Can you please post full [mre]  including ASP.NET Core set up and so on?

Comment: Please post ost whatever calls `UploadAttachments`. I suspect you never `await` that method which means by the time the *second* iteration starts, request processing is over and the uploaded files are already disposed

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos UploadAttachments is awaited

Comment: @MohamedAlmuetazAtifAltayeb your answer proves otherwise. Once again, post your code. Even if `UploadAttachments` is awaited, what about the method that calls it? Your answer proves that one of the functions in the call chain is *not* awaited

Comment: Please post the code for `TaskService.cs`. Is this a background service? A singleton?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Scoped

Answer (score -2):

Ok one of my colleagues solved it for me by changing the code inside the using block

```
using (FileStream stream =  new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        attach.CopyTo(stream);
        stream.Flush();
    }
```

Comment: That's no fix. `CopyToAsync` isn't broken. `CopyToAsync` was the only asynchronous call in the method which means everything before it was running in the original thread. Once `await` was encountered the caller resumed. All the callers need to await all the way to the top (eg the controller action) otherwise the top call exits and the files will be disposed. That's why once `CopyToAsync` completed, the loop found all other files already disposed.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Hopefully what iam about to say isn't wrong {new to dotnet started learning the past month}..ok 
My Under standing for this is when the code reaches the using block then hit await , then the current thread should await the asynchronous  call  of (CopyToAsync) to finish then using will dispose the instance of file stream ... 
So I agree that  CopyToAsync isn't broken. but What occurred is a very strange behavior .

Comment: That's incorrect. `await` doesn't block the calling thread at all. It *releases* it to serve other requests until the asynchronous operation (CopyToAsync) completes. This only applies to `async` method itself though, it won't affect whatever called `UploadAttachments`. That method needs to be `async` as well and `await` your method. So does its caller and so on. If one of them doesn't await, execution will proceed without waiting

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i tried one of your of your suggestions about that one the functions in the call chain is not awaited ,  and totally this fixed the problem the first calling in the controller wasn't awaited .... so i made some changes and it totally worked ........
And Thanks for Explaining how Await actually works... That makes perfect sense